# Insufficient Storage problem in Android x86 Live Version

Tags: applications, internal-storage, insufficient-memory

I made a bootable Android x86 Live USB drive to use android in my computer, I used live version (without installation) of Android x86, it runs fine. The problem is that I am unable to install new apps because of insufficient storage. I have 8 GB of USB drive but the total storage the OS shows is approximately 400 MB and available storage is approximately 80 MB. So now anyone tell me the possible solutions for this problem so that I can install new applications.

Comment: It seems you have created two accounts. See [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: OK, the other one is marked as duplicate, now any help please.